# Get List of Users From Active Directory In A Given AD Group

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have code that searches for all users in a department:

```
string Department = "Billing";
DirectorySearcher LdapSearcher = new DirectorySearcher();
LdapSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
LdapSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
LdapSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("department");
LdapSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("title");
LdapSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
LdapSearcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(department={0}))", Department);
SearchResultCollection src = LdapSearcher.FindAll();
```

What would the filter need to look like if I only wanted everyone in the "Manager Read Only" AD Group?

Am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Looking at your search I have a couple of points for you.  First, the search uses objectClass (non-indexed) instead of objectCategory (indexed).  Huge performance issue with that query.   You would most always want to combine the two together depending on what you are trying to retrieve:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)) = All users (no contacts)
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=contact)) = All contacts (no users)
(&(objectCategory=person)) = All users and contacts
```

As for looking up the users in a group you can enumerate the list of member objects of the specific group.  In the member attribute of the group object is the distinguishedName of each user.

[This article describes enumerating members of a group...](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx#24)

Don't forget that you may have to handle nested groups of the parent group, as there isn't a default way to handle this with LDAP queries.  For that you may need to evaluate if the member object is a group and then get the member attribute for that child group.

Lastly, you should get in the habit of specifying a dns prefix to your query.

Without DNS prefix:

```
LDAP://ou=ouname,dc=domain,dc=com
```

With DNS prefix (all three work):

```
LDAP://servername/ou=ouname,dc=domain,dc=com
LDAP://servername.domain.com/ou=ouname,dc=domain,dc=com
LDAP://domain.com/ou=ouname,dc=domain,dc=com
```

A single domain won't cause you much issue but when you try and run a search in a multiple domain environment you will get bitten without this addition.  Hope this helps move you closer to your goal.

Comment: That was a very thoughtful reply.

Comment: Adding (objectCategory=person) really made the search noticeably faster.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wrong. In the member attribute of the group object is the distinguishedName of each user, OR ANOTHER **GROUP** NAME...

Answer (score 11):

I've always found [Howto: (Almost) Everything In Active Directory via C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx) helps for most AD questions.

Comment: This is a really comprehensive article but I didn't find this one specifically.  That doesn't mean it's not there, just that I couldn't see it.  I'm juggling a dozen things right now ...

Comment: This link is broken. I think this is what should be used now http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90142/Everything-in-Active-Directory-via-C-NET-Using

Comment: Also http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C

Answer (score 6):

If you know the AD path to the group already it would probably be easier to open a DirectoryEntry on that, then do a DirectorySearcher from there.

```
using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://somedomain/CN=FooBar"))
{
   DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(de, ("(objectClass=user)"));
}
```

There is also a flag on the Searcher for whether to drill down to sub containers, I forget the name off hand.

Comment: That would be for the AD Group FooBar? (Sorry I'm kinda new to this stuff)

Comment: Yes. Everything in AD has a Distinguished Name (its path)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366101(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

I use following code (from http://blogs.technet.com/b/brad_rutkowski/archive/2008/04/15/c-getting-members-of-a-group-the-easy-way-with-net-3-5-discussion-groups-nested-recursive-security-groups-etc.aspx) it works fine.

```
IList<string> getMembers(string domainName, string groupName)
    {
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
        GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, groupName);

        if (grp == null) { 
            throw new ApplicationException("We did not find that group in that domain, perhaps the group resides in a different domain?");
        }

        IList<string> members = new List<String>();

        foreach (Principal p in grp.GetMembers(true))
        {
            members.Add(p.Name); //You can add more attributes, samaccountname, UPN, DN, object type, etc... 
        }
        grp.Dispose();
        ctx.Dispose();

        return members;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Search for Group and list group members

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

namespace ExportActiveDirectoryGroupsUsers
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("args is null, useage: ExportActiveDirectoryGroupsUsers OutputPath"); // Check for null array
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("args length is ");
                Console.WriteLine(args.Length); // Write array length
                for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) // Loop through array
                {
                    string argument = args[i];
                    Console.Write("args index ");
                    Console.Write(i); // Write index
                    Console.Write(" is [");
                    Console.Write(argument); // Write string
                    Console.WriteLine("]");
                }
                try
                {
                    using (var ServerContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ServerAddress, Username, Password))
                    {
                        /// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a GroupPrincipal 
                        GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ServerContext, args[0]);

                        // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
                        PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);

                        // find all matches
                        foreach (var found in srch.FindAll())
                        {
                            GroupPrincipal foundGroup = found as GroupPrincipal;

                            if (foundGroup != null)
                            {
                                // iterate over members
                                foreach (Principal p in foundGroup.GetMembers())
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("{0}|{1}", foundGroup.Name, p.DisplayName);
                                    // do whatever you need to do to those members
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    //Console.WriteLine("end");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Something wrong happened in the AD Query module: " + ex.ToString());
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```