# How can I list all SPUser objects in a SPGroup?

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, spgroup, spuser

I need to retrieve all `SPUser`'s from a `SPGroup`. Unfortunately, the group may contain Active Directory groups, so a simple `SPGroup.Users` is not enough (I'd just get a single `SPUser` for the AD group, with the `IsDomainGroup` property set to true).

Does anyone have a good idea how can I obtain a list of all `SPUser`'s, descending into any Active Directory groups contained in a `SPGroup`? Is there an alternative to `SPGroup.ContainsCurrentUser` that takes a `SPUser` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a [blog post I found](http://chrissyblanco.blogspot.com/2007/07/determining-whether-user-is-member-of.html), I have written the following code:

```
private static List<SPUser> ListUsers(SPWeb web, SPPrincipal group)
{
    try
    {
        web.Site.CatchAccessDeniedException = false;
        var users = new List<SPUser>();
        foreach(SPUser user in web.SiteUsers)
        {
            using(var userContextSite = new SPSite(web.Site.ID, user.UserToken))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var userContextWeb = userContextSite.OpenWeb(web.ID))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (userContextWeb.SiteGroups[group.Name]
                                .ContainsCurrentUser)
                                    users.Add(user);
                        }
                        catch (SPException)
                        {
                            // group not found, continue
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    // user does not have right to open this web, continue
                }
            }
        }
        return users;
    }
    finally
    {
        web.Site.CatchAccessDeniedException = true;
    }
}
```

I don't like the fact that I have to impersonate every single user, and this code will only find AD users that have already been imported into SharePoint (so an `SPUser` exists for them), but that's good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it may be the case that not every member of the AD group has a corresponding SPUser object in the site (yet).

In this scenario, I'd enumerate all the members of the active directory group, and force them into the site with the SPWeb's `EnsureUser()` method, which returns an `SPUser`, and creates a new one if it doesn't already exist in the site.

For guidance on enumerating active directory members, see [Get List of Users From Active Directory In A Given AD Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513124/get-list-of-users-from-active-directory-in-a-given-ad-group).