# Querying LDAP for Usergroup of Specific User

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ldap-query, usergroups

I have to check usergroups of LDAP Active Directory for a specific user in C#. Mean I pass this username to a method and it returns me list of group from that user belongs. Can You Please help me in this. Im Searching alot But Everytime get new error.

LDAP Path: 192.168.1.4

Domain Name: Arslan

UserName: ArslanP

Password: testad

Comment: Post the code that's giving you problems and maybe we can help with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

[Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)

Basically, add a reference to the assembly `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`, and then you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

public List<GroupPrincipal> GetGroupsForUser(string username)
{
  List<GroupPrincipal> result = new List<GroupPrincipal>();

  // set up domain context - if you do a lot of requests, you might
  // want to create that outside the method and pass it in as a parameter
  PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

  // find user by name
  UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(username);

  // get the user's groups
  if(user != null)
  {
     foreach(GroupPrincipal gp in user.GetAuthorizationGroups())
     {
         result.Add(gp);
     }    
  }

  return result;
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD:

Answer (score 0):

This related question may help you:

[Get List of Users From Active Directory In A Given AD Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513124/get-list-of-users-from-active-directory-in-a-given-ad-group)

It asks the reverse question, which is how to qet a list of users when you know the group, but other answers may be of use to you as well.

See also the answer to this question:

[How to get all the AD groups for a particular user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460558/how-to-get-all-the-ad-groups-for-a-particular-user)