# Find Usergroups using LDAP Authentication

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am using the following code to do LDAP authentication

```
   PrincipalContext _loginContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain.com");
_isAuthSuccess = _loginContext.ValidateCredentials(myUserName, myPassword);
if (_isAuthSuccess)
{
//assume the validation is OK 
}
```

This code is working fine and  i am able to decide the user is authenticated or not.

But now i have to find the user belongs to a particular user group (active directory user group ) and if its , then only allow login . 
So how can i find the user belongs to what all groups in C#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get List of Users From Active Directory In A Given AD Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513124/get-list-of-users-from-active-directory-in-a-given-ad-group)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all the AD groups for a particular user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460558/how-to-get-all-the-ad-groups-for-a-particular-user)